# makefile compiles all files instead of the last edited ones

Tags: c++, makefile

Note that there are similar questions on SO, however I think my situation is different, moreover my Makefile is extremely simple and straight forward. I am new to Makefile.

Suppose I need to compile a project, that looks like this --

```
.
├── [4.0K]  bin
├── [ 517]  Makefile
├── [4.0K]  obj
└── [4.0K]  src
    ├── [ 117]  func1.cpp
    ├── [  76]  func2.cpp
    ├── [ 137]  global.h
    └── [  97]  main1.cpp
```

and my Makefile looks like this --

```
CC          := g++
CFLAGS      := -g -Wall -std=c++0x
LDFLAGS     := -lm

NAMES   := func1.cpp func2.cpp main1.cpp
SRC     := $(addprefix src/,$(NAMES))
OBJ     := $(addprefix obj/,$(NAMES:.cpp=.o))
DEPS    := $(OBJ:.o=.d)

.PHONY: clean all debug

all: prog

debug:
    $(info $$SRC: ${SRC})
    $(info $$OBJ: ${OBJ})
    $(info $$DEPS: ${DEPS})

prog: bin/prog

bin/prog: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

$(OBJ): $(SRC)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I/src/global.h -c $(addprefix src/,$(notdir $(@:.o=.cpp))) -o $@

-include $(DEPS)

clean:
    rm -rf bin/*
    rm -rf obj/*
```

Suppose I opened a file `func1.cpp` and made some changes. When I invoke `make` it compiles all files, but it was supposed to compile only one (`func1.cpp`).

How do I fix this ?

**Note:** I need `prog`, `bin/prog` for a different reason, also I can't do recipes like `obj/%.o: src/%.c` because I might have different target from the subset of the same objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make Makefile to recompile only changed files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815400/how-do-i-make-makefile-to-recompile-only-changed-files)

Comment: I suspect you just need to add `-MMD -MP` to your `CFLAGS`. Or maybe just to your `$(OBJ): $(SRC)` target's command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write a rule like:

```
$(OBJ): $(SRC)
    cmd
```

which in your case is

```
obj/func1.o obj/func2.o obj/main.o : src/func1.cpp src/func2.cpp src/main1.cpp
    cmd
```

The prerequisites don't get zipped across. That generates one rule for each target, with all of the prerequisites. That is:

```
obj/func1.o : src/func1.cpp src/func2.cpp src/main1.cpp
    cmd

obj/func2.o : src/func1.cpp src/func2.cpp src/main1.cpp
    cmd

obj/main.o : src/func1.cpp src/func2.cpp src/main1.cpp
    cmd
```

Since `src/func1.cpp` is a prereq for all of the object files, they all get recompiled.

What you want instead is to use a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Usage):

```
obj/%.o : src/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I/src -c $< -o $@
```

Note that `-I` is for include *directories*, not include files.