# Makefile compiled all target files instead of the lastest modified file

Tags: linux, makefile, f2py

I've check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39836609/makefile-compiles-all-files-instead-of-the-last-edited-ones) but I think it is not the same situation of mine.

I'm using [f2py](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/f2py/) to compile my fortran code, so that I can import this fortran code in python.
For example, I have two fortran files: `t.f90` and `t2.f90`, and using this command to compile:

```
$ f2py -c t.f90 -m f90t
$ f2py -c t2.f90 -m f90t2
```

and two .so files are generated: `f90t.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` and `f90t2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.

I want to use Makefile to compile these files. My Makefile is like this:

```
FILES = t.f90 t2.f90

NAMES = $(basename $(FILES))
TARGET = $(addprefix f90, $(NAMES))

all : $(TARGET)

f90% : %.f90
    @echo "Compile $< to $@"
    f2py -c $< -m $@

.PHONY : clean
clean : 
    rm f90*.so
```

The Makefile can work without error, but something is strange. If I change the content of one fortran file and execute Makefile, it still "compile" two fortran file, but actually the output file is not changed.

Like this:

```sh
$ ls       # run.py will execute the function of t.f90 and t2.f90
Makefile run.py t.f90 t2.f90
$ make
Compile t.f90 to f90t
....
Compile t2.f90 to f90t2
....
$ python run.py
"This line is printed by t.f90"
"This line is printed by t2.f90"
$ vim t2.f90     # adding some exclamation mark
$ make           # I only modified t2.f90, but t.f90 is also compiled
Compile t.f90 to f90t
....
Compile t2.f90 to f90t2
....
$ python run.py       # still the old result
"This line is printed by t.f90"
"This line is printed by t2.f90"
$ make clean
$ make
Compile t.f90 to f90t
....
Compile t2.f90 to f90t2
....
$ python run.py       # finally ok
"This line is printed by t.f90"
"This line is printed by t2.f90 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
```

I have no idea why this happened. Can anyone help?
Any suggestion is grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your makefile expects that `f90t` and `f90t2` are built, but as you say

> two .so files are generated: f90t.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

So, on next run, make does not find `f90t` and calls the command again.  You can do something like

```
    @touch $@
```

at the end of the rule or rename the targets.

Comment: Very Thanks! I misunderstood that I can ignore the extension of target file. Adding `@touch $@` can work.

Comment: But using `@touch $@` would generate unneeded files `f90t` and `f90t2`. I was wondering that if I can just adding extension of target file? That is, change target from `f90t` to `f90t.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`. But if I use this method, it would create folders `f90t/` and 'f90t2/' instead of .so files. How to solve this problem?

Comment: it is a common practice to create such helper files/targets; usually they are "hidden" by making them a dot file (e..g ".f90x.stamp").  Of course, you can use the full name, but this seems to be complicated because it contains dynamic information (host architecture + os).

Comment: OK I see, it seems that create a hidden file `.f90t1` and `.f90t2` is a great idea. I have modified my Makefile and the result is totally what I want. Very thank you!