# cannot execute binary file: Exec format error 64bits

Tags: bash, gcc, binaryfiles, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm under Windows Linux Subsystem which works well on other computer.

I have a 64-bits file: `./ensembles.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped`

`uname -m`: `x86_64`

I tried with the `gcc` compiler and the `clang` one, both loose.

Even this C code doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "sac.h"
#include "type_ensemble.h"
#include "operations_ens.h"
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
}
```

The error: `-bash: ./ensembles.o: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

My Makefile:

```
ensembles.o : ensembles.c sac.h type_ensemble.h operations_ens.h
    gcc -c ensembles.c
operation_ens.o : operations_ens.c operations_ens.h
    gcc -c operations_ens.c
sac.o : sac.c sac.h
    gcc -c sac.c
main: ensembles.o operation_ens.o sac.o
    gcc -o main ensembles.o operation_ens.o sac.o
```

Comment: You said you tried, but what exactly did you try? And what do you mean by "loose"?

Comment: I tried to execute the compiled program. `./ensembles.o`. I meant fail to compile it so it can be ran.

Comment: `ensembles.o` is not a compiled program, it's an object file.

Comment: What exactly did you do with gcc and clang? Your question says you used them (somehow), but your comment says you simply ran `./ensembles.o`, which doesn't involve either.

Comment: I added my Makefile

Comment: OK, so you need to `make main` and run `./main`. Why are you trying to execute intermediate object files?

Comment: I don't know, I'm probably dumb ^^

Comment: Use this to create makefile: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815400/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file of type *ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable* is a file of ELF type ET_REL, which is not directly executable.  It's commonly called an object file or `.o` file, and it is an input file for the link editor.

You need to link it (either with the `gcc` or the `ld` command) to produce an executable.  If you are invoking `gcc`, you must not pass options like `-r` or `-c`, or otherwise GCC will not produce an executable.

In the makefile you quote, only the first target will be executed by make because it is the default target.  Try moving the rule for `main` to the beginning of the file, or add a rule

```
all: main
```

at the beginning.  You can also invoke `make main` to request building the `main` file explicitly.

Comment: I understand now, but how to link all my Object files?

Comment: @Izio `gcc -o main ensembles.o operation_ens.o sac.o`, last line in your Makefile.

Comment: @lzio Your executable is called `main`, but it is not built because of the way you have written the makefile.